# Extracting Spatial Points that match Raster Value using R?

Tags: raster, r, sp

I have a question concerning the extraction of spatial points that match a certain value of an additional raster in R. The operation itself should actually be pretty simple, but I'm stuck somehow. (I am using R at a "lower intermediate" level).

I am using two data sets. The first one is a shapefile containing point data.

```
training1 <- shapefile ("re_27042015projcrop_all.shp")
```

The second one is a "binary mask" raster object consisting solely of 0 and 1 values.

```
radar1 <- brick ("binary_01_180115_240415.envi")
```

How do I extract all points whose coordinates match raster pixels with a value of 1?

I tried some logical expressions like

```
output <- training1@coords & radar1==1
```

and various raster functions like crop, mask etc., but none seemed to work.

Comment: By "points whose coordinates match raster pixels" do you mean the point is somewhere within the raster cell or it is exactly at the centre of the cell?

Comment: I mean somewhere within the raster cell. Basically, the idea of my operation is similar to the clip function in ArcGIS, except that I want to use raster cells of a certain value as the clip feature.

Comment: `extract(r, pts)` will get the raster values at the points, and then you can subset that for values==1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a logic test to select those points. With an example:

```r
library(raster)
library(sp)

set.seed(123)

# raster creation
r <- raster()

# values 0 and 1
r <- setValues(r, sample(x = 0:1, size = ncell(r), replace = T))

# point creation
pts <- spsample(as(r@extent,"SpatialPolygons"),100,type='random')
```

`r` is a binary raster and `pts` is a point layer with 100 features, let's see raster values of points position:

```r
head(extract(r,pts))
## [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

We have 0 and 1 values, to select only the points with position over values equal to 0, it's necessary to create a logic vector and select rows with this vector:

```r
ones <- which(extract(r == 1,pts) == 1)

pts2 <- pts[ones,]
```

Now, let's see values of this new layer:

```r
head(extract(r,pts2))

## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```